# No suitable driver found Orientdb jdbc driver

Tags: database-design, java, jdbc, document-oriented

I have some problems with Orientdb driver for jdbc.
i´m using Netbeans, i have include the library JDBC+OrientDB libraries (orientdb-jdbc-2.0.8-all.jar) in the directory and in netbeans, i have also include the connector in the proyect (i have include the connector in the Classpath),
but i still have the same problem :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:orient:remote:localhost/GratefulDeadConcerts
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
at Aconexion.AConexion.main(AConexion.java:15)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

my code:

```
package Aconexion;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Properties;
import com.orientechnologies.orient.jdbc.OrientJdbcConnection;
public class AConexion {
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {

Properties info = new Properties();
info.put("user", "admin");
info.put("password", "admin");
Connection conn = (OrientJdbcConnection) 
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:orient:remote:localhost/GratefulDeadConcerts", info);
try{

Class.forName("com.orientechnologies.orient.jdbc.OrientJdbcDriver");
Connection connection = (OrientJdbcConnection)
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:orient:remote:localhost/GratefulDeadConcerts", info);
}catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
}
```

[image: Code example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is that you need to put in a direct way the user, eliminate info

DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:orient:remote:localhost/GratefulDeadConcerts", "root", "password");

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the JDBC driver needs to be loaded before the connection is made by Class.forName("com.orientechnologies.orient.jdbc.OrientJdbcDriver").